# $X \sim N(0;4) ,Y=2X^2+4X-5$. Find $P(Y<X)$

Tags: probability

$X \sim N(0;4) , Y=2X^2+4X-5$.

Find $P(Y<X)$.

Denote $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}=\frac{X}{2} \sim N(0;1)$ (since $X \sim N(0;4)$).

I have to find the distribution of Y.

Firstly, I know that $4X-5 \sim N(4\cdot0-5,4^2\cdot4)$ but how I deal with $2X^2$?

$P(Y<X)=1-P(X<Y)=1-P(X<2X^2+4X-5)=1-P(0<2X^2+3X-5)$

I am really get stuck here and need some help.

Thanks !

Comment: Hint: complete the square

Comment: Here knowing the distribution of $Y$ might not help as much as one might think, since $Y$ is definitely not independent from $X$. (If one must find the distribution of $Y$, it's probably best to write it as $Y=2(X+1)^2-7$.) Hint: For what real numbers $x$ do we have $2x^2+4x-5<x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} P(Y<X) &= P(2X^2+4X-5<X) =\\
&= P(2X^2+3X-5<0)= \\
&= P(-1 < X<\frac52)\end{align}
where the last equality is obtained by solving the quadratic inequality.